# Another way to express "was woken up suddenly."

Tags: idioms

I wish to express the action of a person being woken up abruptly from sleep by a loud noise, such as an explosion. But the desired impact is missing from my writing. Please provide a phrase or an idiom that could be of use.

Comment: "I get up when I want, except on Wednesdays, when *I get rudely awakened* by the dustman" - lyrics to Parklife by Blur.

Comment: Do not ask for help writing or proofreading. They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

***jolt out of*** sleep

From [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jolt+out+of):

> **jolt out of**
>
> **jolt someone out of something**
>
> *to startle someone out of inertness.*
>
> The cold water thrown in her face was what it took to jolt Mary out of
>   her deep sleep.
>
> At the sound of the telephone, he jolted himself out of his stupor.

Answer (score 1):

**startled awake**
or the somewhat milder but related
**woke with a start**

[startle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/startle)

> To cause to make a quick involuntary movement or start.
>
> To alarm, frighten, or surprise suddenly

[start](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/start)

> To move one's body or a part of it suddenly or involuntarily

[Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=startled%20awake%2Cwoke%20with%20a%20start%2C%20jolted%20out%20of%20sleep%2C%20jolted%20awake&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstartled%20awake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoke%20with%20a%20start%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjolted%20out%20of%20sleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjolted%20awake%3B%2Cc0) of some different versions.